# ForEach nested in List - stop producing rows when row count hits particular point

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, foreach

I have a list with a nested ForEach loop that *should* take the data and stop producing rows once the row counter hits three, but I'm receiving the following error message

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View

Is it possible to cut off the loop once we have three rows displaying? My end goal is once three rows are displayed, to show a "View More" button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeListView: View {
    @State var listofRecipes: [RecipeListModel] = RecipeList.recipes
    @State private var recipeCounter = 0
    
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Recipes")
                .padding(.bottom, -20)
                //.padding(.top, 40)
                .font(.title2)
            
            List{
                ForEach(listofRecipes, id: \.id){ recipe in
                recipeCounter += 1
                    if(recipeCounter < 3){
                        
                        HStack{
                            Image(recipe.image)
                                .resizable()
                               .frame (width: 70, height:70)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                                
                            VStack{
                                Text(recipe.name)
                                    .font(.title2)
                                //temp solution until I can center it
                                    .padding(.trailing, 25)
                              
                                NavigationLink(destination: {RecipeController(name: recipe.name, image: recipe.image)}, label: {
                                   Text("View Recipe")
                                       .padding(5)
                                       .foregroundColor(.black)
                                       .background(Color("completeGreen"))
                                       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                       .cornerRadius(14)
                                     
                                    })
                                    .padding(4)
                                    
                                }
                            
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type cannot conform to view because you can't change the variables in the view. You can declare `let`, use `if` or `switch`, but you can't declare a `var` or change the value directly - so, `recipeCounter += 1` is not allowed.

One solution is to create a temporary list that contains only the first 3 items, then change it to the full list after the user decides to see the rest.

The example below has some explanations of what each part of the code does:

```
struct Example: View {
    
    // The full list is a let constant
    let fullList = [Recipe("First"),
                    Recipe("Second"),
                    Recipe("Third"),
                    Recipe("Fourth"),
                    Recipe("Fifth")]
    
    // The list is a @State variable: .onAppear will set
    // it to contain the first 3 items, then it'll change
    // to the full list
    @State private var listofRecipes = [Recipe]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Recipes")
                .font(.title2)
                .padding()
            
            List{
                ForEach(listofRecipes, id: \.id){ recipe in
                    Text(recipe.text)
                }
            }
            
            // "Show more" button: will change the list
            // to make it contain all the items
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    listofRecipes = fullList
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Show more")
            }
        }
        
        // When the view appears, set the list to contain only the
        // first 3 items
        .onAppear {

            // Handle case when the list contains only 3 elements or less
            if fullList.count > 3 {
                listofRecipes = fullList.dropLast(fullList.count - 3)
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct Recipe {
        let id = UUID()
        let text: String
        init(_ text: String) {
            self.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @HunterLion - thank you for the response. Quick question, how is it if you drop last and then - 3 it will remain at a count of 3 rows? In the example above, if you drop last they'll be 4 rows left, then if you subtract 3 one row?

Comment: @JimCiaston: The example above drops an amount of `fullList.count - 3` items, meaning that it drops *all* items except 3. So, there will always be 3 rows left, before expanding the list manually. Did I correctly get your question?

Comment: ahh gotcha, thanks again!

Comment: @JimCiaston: your comment reminded me that I hadn't handled the case when the list contains 3 items or less - there could be a crash. I edited the code to handle that case and avoid such issues.

Comment: You didn't have to do that, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As @HunterLion mentioned, the problem is caused by `recipeCounter += 1`.

Another way to solve this is to use the list index directly in your condition:

```
ForEach(listofRecipes.indices) { index in
    if(index < 3) {
       HStack {
          Image(listofRecipes[index].image)
           ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to what the two others said is to use the [.prefix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix) modifier on `listofRecipes`.  This will return a subsequence of your array with the first n elements.

```
ForEach(listofRecipes.prefix(3)) { recipe in
     HStack {
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciate it!